# I take image and stored into my sdcard and file name path stored into db

Tags: android, cordova

Captured image is stored into sdcard and for viewing data from sdcard, path name is stored database. But sometimes path is getting saved as NULL in db.

```
// click on camera
takePic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // take pic
            if((takePicRedBtn.isChecked())) {

                    captureImage();//capture image 

            }});
    }

//capturing image
private void captureImage() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);

    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);

    // start the image capture Intent
    startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE);

}

// inside on Activity Result
if(requestCode == CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE)  
{
   if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        // successfully captured the image

        //here i insert path name into db       
        takePicIntoDb();
    }
```

Comment: Use the command line, because the other way is very difficult, you have to put all the files by hand to the right place and you have to do all the settings by yourselve.

Comment: thanq u for comment so can u explain in sort how to do using with command line bcoz no idea about this     i go through with this can u but its not working cmd throughing error not recognized internal and external command ..and i also have setup environment variables java,android,sdk, and ant also

Comment: pls helm me i'm stucking from 2 days..its not solved

Comment: Never use short hand language on Stack Overflow. We respect your time. You are not on Whats App. Write proper English please.

Comment: Put the error log and code by which you extract file path and save it to DB.

Comment: there is not any error only some times it takes path after capturing and some times it take null into db

Comment: i have doubt that when and where should I call to store file name or path name into db either inside on activity result or after calling of data stored into sd card